# Laravel after upload weird look

Tags: laravel, iis, twitter-bootstrap-3, windows-server

I have a weird problem, everything with my Laravel app is setupped and was working fine both in local server and shared linux server, now in dedicated windows server some fonts has been larger and some functions are not working properly such as twitter bootstrap confirmation model, it reduces the background light but it doesn't show the pop up as well as footer items has no padding, it have came to the very top of the footer. I checked the inspect elements and everything is loaded. Have anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: share some code and images if you could

Comment: I faced a similar problem because of the css, js etc files paths. Making the relative paths to absolute paths(relative to the project) worked for me.

Comment: and how to make relative path to absolute path?

Comment: <script src="{{ URL::asset('./assets/js/main.js') }}"></script> this is my structure to include js and css files.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{{ URL::asset('assets/js/main.js') }}`?

Comment: yes, but ./ works better as for Linux you must be very precise with the links. So it helps to be precise and the link works fine even from the view page source option of chrome when u click on the link, it views the file directly.